# Android studio does not show a new created directory

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new directory (example: values-da) in my "res" directory, it does not show my created directory. No matter what the directory is named. it just won't showing. I re-created the directory again and it says that the directory already exist. I closed the program and open it again but my created directory is still not showing.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is because you do not have any resources in that directory and you are using the Android project view.

Click on the "Android" drop-down that is shown in the upper-left corner of your screenshot. Change it to "Project". that will give you an accurate depiction of the directory structure of your project.

Comment: @prouser135: It is not just you. Lots and lots of developers get confused by the Android project view. I tell everyone to switch it to Project, at least until you get a lot more comfortable with Android development.

Comment: Why oh why is the default to NOT show empty directories?  Keeping them hidden makes it _very_ difficult to add files to those directories.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

i just get rid of this problam, don't create folder in capa

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31165241)